# Dynamically change generic variable name when implemented

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Lets say I have a simple interface:

```
public interface ISender<T>
{
    void Send(T t);
}
```

When I implement this using Visual Studio's auto-implementation, I get something like this:

```
public class StreamSender : ISender(Stream)
{
    public void Send(Stream t)
    { ... }
}
```

Seems pretty straight forward, but what if I wanted Visual Studio to automatically rename my `t` type parameter to match whatever type I used as the generic type parameter (as a string), so for `StreamSender : ISender<Stream>` it would be `public void Send(Stream stream)` or `ISender<String>` would be `public void Send(String string)` etc.

Is this possible using Visual Studio's templates?

Edit: I know I can just rename `t` after implementing the interface since the name of the implementing method parameters doesn't have to match the interface, I am more curious to see if automatic renaming is *possible* period.

Comment: Consider naming it something related to its purpose, like `input` or `objectToSend`. For example, `IEquatable<T>.Equals` takes a parameter called `other`, which makes sense regardless of what `T` is.

Comment: You can place your mouse on the wave line, and click "Show potential fixes" or press "Alt + Enter". Then choose "Implement interface".